# Did I make a mistake in my proof of triangular ineqality by squaring both sides?

Tags: solution-verification, triangle-inequality

I have a proof of the triangular inequality given below:

**Theorem**: For any real numbers $x$ and $y$, $|x + y| \leq |x| + |y|$.

**Proof**:

\begin{align}
      (x + y)^2 &\leq (|x| + |y|)^2\tag{square both sides} \\
      (x + y)^2 &\leq x^2 + 2|x||y| + y^2\tag{expand right-hand side} \\
      x^2 + 2xy + y^2 &\leq x^2 + 2|x||y| + y^2\tag{expand left-hand side}\\
      2xy &\leq 2|x||y|\tag{eliminate like terms}\\
      xy &\leq |xy|\tag{simplify}\\
      (xy)^2 &\leq (xy)^2\tag{square both sides}\\
      \texttt{True}
\end{align}

I was worried that squaring both sides of an inequality in the last line of transformation might be incorrect because $xy$ is not necessarily positive. But I don't know how to prove that $xy \leq |xy|$ otherwise.

Comment: I dont think you need proof for $xy \leq |xy|$.  Because if $xy$ is positive, we have equality.  If $xy$ is negative, it is clearly less than the positive number $|xy|$

Comment: A couple of other things to think about. First, you are squaring both sides in the first line, not just the last. Second, your proof is heading in the wrong direction, i.e., you are starting by assuming what you want to prove.

Answer (score 1):

I think one does not actually need to prove that $xy \le |xy|$ as it's obvious. However, as long as you want to know how to prove it, here is the hint:

1. Check and compare the product when both $x$ and $y$ have the same sign with its absolute value. Ensure your inequality is true.
2. Check and compare the product when $x$ and $y$ have different signs (so the product has to be negative) with its absolute value. Ensure your inequality is true.

Then you're done.